# xpath: How to get EXACTLY next node (siblings)

Tags: xpath

I have HTML organized like below.

```
<div class="statement">
</div>
<div class="reply">
</div>
<div class="statement">
</div>
<div class="statement">
</div>
<div class="reply">
</div>
<div class="statement">
</div>
<div class="statement">
</div>
<div class="reply">
</div>
```

It's random whether there is a reply div or not next to statement div.
What i want is to select the reply div class while knowing which nth statement it is. I thought to iterate every statement (by iterate variable, ofc), and in this case:

```
(//div[@class="statement"])[1]/following-sibling::div[@class="reply"]
```

i end up got all following replies.
So, how to get exactly one next following sibling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the first following `div` that has `@class='reply'`

```
following-sibling::div[@class="reply"][1]
```

This will get the first following `div` provided that it has `@class='reply'`

```
following-sibling::div[1][@class="reply"]
```

I wasn't quite sure which of these you wanted.

Comment: what i want is the second one. Thanks a lot!